# How to disable browser from rendering old values in the input tags of form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Usually when we fill input in the form and submit it then the next time when we input values in the same form then browser renders the previously filled values below it even when we are giving input in the textbox. How to disable that programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing this because users can manually disable the option on their browsers if they don't want it.

It might be possible to just erase the content of all inputs once the page is done loading, but only if the browsers implements this feature by actually setting the values as the page is loaded.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; ++i) {
    inputs[i].value = "";
}
```